# Unable to pass parameter through Ajax in Laravel using GET method

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to pass a parameter through Ajax using GET method in Laravel. For testing purpose, I am trying to get the same parameter value in the response. But the response I am getting is `{code}`.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "{{ url('helpers/get-item-details/{code}') }}",
    data: {
        code: 100390,
    },
    success:function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        $('input[name="hs_code"]').val(response.hs_code);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Invalid response");
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
        alert(jqXHR.responseText);
    }
});
```

**Controller:**

```
class Helper
{
    public static function getItemDetails($itemId){            
        return $itemId;
    }
}
```

Not sure where it is going wrong. I tried to call the URL on the browser like following which returns the parameter value as expected.

```
helpers/get-item-details/100390
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/helpers/get-item-details/{id}', 'App\Helpers\Helper@getItemDetails');
```

Comment: How does the route look like ?

Comment: Route::get('/helpers/get-item-details/{id}', 'App\Helpers\Helper@getItemDetails');

Comment: var code = 100390;   then   url: "{{ url('helpers/get-item-details)?code=$code }}",   OR  try this   url: "{{ url('helpers/get-item-details) }}?code=$code"

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue with my code at last. This code was working in another project for me. What I got wrong is in my controller. There I had to take the parameter as a Request object in the function definition. Instead I had set it as a variable.

**Correct Controller Code:**

```
class Helper
{
    public static function getItemDetails(Request $request){
        return $request->code;
   }
}
```

Thanks for all of your contribution.